# TeamCity only updating certain assembly versions

Tags: teamcity

I'm using AssemblyInfo patcher to update versions of assemblies and only some assemblies are being updated.I'm performing a 'Clean Build'. 
The version of the assemblies that's not being updated remains: 1.0.0.0

This has been happening for about 5 months (Only picked it up now) so it is difficult to pinpoint what could be causing this.

Current version: 2019.1.3

Sorry for the open ended question but does anyone have any ideas on this?

Teamcity config:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the build log contain anything on this point?

Comment: @YanSklyarenko, nothing specific about the versions. Only logging details that it is actually updating the assemblyInfo.cs files with the new version details

Comment: @YanSklyarenko, had a look at the assemblyInfo.cs files and although the build log does mention that it is adding version info to all assemblyInfo.cs files it seems that the version info is only being inserted in some of them.

Comment: The docs say: "*Note that this feature will work only for standard projects, i.e. created by means of the Visual Studio wizard, so that all the AssemblyInfo files and content have a standard location.*" Perhaps, those files which are not patched are located in different folders and are simply not picked by the patcher?

Answer (score 0):

Assembly version attributes were missing from some of the assemblyInfo.cs files:

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]